# Can we convert the mojo based application to enyo based application

Tags: webos

I am haveing  mojo based applications(.ipk) so can convert those ipk into enyo based ipk

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Mojo and Enyo are different javascript frameworks.
I made an app called instagrio and tried to convert it into enyo, found that was almost impossible.
Enyo has no scenes, and lots webOS features are deprived in Enyo2.0.